I want to photograph vehicle procession, no blurring needed
I want to photograph a procession for a fallen officier. It will be interstate highway traffic. Public traffic limited (if not stopped all together). Normal speed limit 65, but most likely reduced. Time of procession will be 4:30-5:00pm. Local law enforcement officers will be positioned on a bridge over interstate. Possibly overcast skies. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

What is your question? Where will you be photographing? "no blurring needed", what does that mean? Are you trying to make sure there's no blur?
